# Pandas 'get_dummies' for specific factors

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a `df` like this one:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['id', 'factor_var']
values = [
    [1, 'a'],
    [2, 'a'],
    [3, 'a'],
    [4, 'b'],
    [5, 'b'],
    [6, 'c'],
    [7, 'c'],
    [8, 'c'],
    [9, 'c'],
    [10, 'c'],
    [11, 'd'],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=cols)
```

My target `df` has the following columns:

```
target_columns = ['id', 'factor_var_a', 'factor_var_b', 'factor_var_other']
```

The column `factor_var_other` being all categories in the `factor_var` that are not `a` or `b`, disregarding the frequency in which each category appears.

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace non matched values of list by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html), reassign back by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and last call [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
s = df['factor_var'].where(df['factor_var'].isin(['a','b']), 'other')
#alternative
#s = df['factor_var'].map({'a':'a','b':'b'}).fillna('other')
df = pd.get_dummies(df.assign(factor_var=s), columns=['factor_var'])
print (df)
    id  factor_var_a  factor_var_b  factor_var_other
0    1             1             0                 0
1    2             1             0                 0
2    3             1             0                 0
3    4             0             1                 0
4    5             0             1                 0
5    6             0             0                 1
6    7             0             0                 1
7    8             0             0                 1
8    9             0             0                 1
9   10             0             0                 1
10  11             0             0                 1
```